# ¿Errores en modelo de base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buen día, actualmente estoy creando un sistema para una biblioteca, tengo realizado el modelo, pero me gustaría alguna sugerencia o saber que puedo mejorar del mismo, pues no me siento conforme y tampoco soy muy experto en el tema.

[image: Diagrama EER]

De antemano gracias, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Comment: Es una pregunta interesante, incluso se preocupa por esos detalles que marcan la diferencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay unas consideraciones para tener en cuenta, digamos que son "**las buenas prácticas**", y reducir algún tipo de problema a futuro, como de rendimiento, simplificar sintaxis, que los nombres tengan sentido y sea intuitivo:

1. Todas las tablas deben ser InnoDB y por lo menos con las propiedades CHARSET=UTF-8 y COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci.
2. Todas las tablas deben tener una columna llamada "id" que es un Primary Key con las siguientes características: BITINT, UNSIGNED, NOT NULL y AUTO_INCREMENT.
3. Todas las columnas que son FOREIGN KEY deben tener las siguientes características: BITINT, UNSIGNED, y el CONSTRAINT.
4. Evitar que el CONSTRAINT tenga una acción en cascada, por ejemplo: Que al eliminar un registro padre no elimine automaticamente sus hijos.
5. Tener una nomenclatura constante para nombrar columnas de tipo FOREIGN KEY, por ejemplo: user_id, profile_id ó address_id.
6. Evitar en lo posible usar FOREIGN KEY con la posibilidad de permitir NULL.
7. No crear un índice exclusivo de una columna que tiene el CONSTRAINT del FOREIGN KEY, ya el CONSTRAINT define el indice.
8. Si es posible, agregar un CONSTRAINT de tipo UNIQUE para evitar registros duplicados, por ejemplo: el UNIQUE para un email.
9. Ser concientes de las diferencias que hay entre los tipos de datos como; CHAR, VARCHAR, ENUM, TEXT entre sus variantes. Cada uno tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, cada uno influye en la optimización de memoria, tiempo de respuesta y/o busqueda o penaliza en disco.
10. No usar palabras reservadas como nombres de columnas.
11. Tener columas de auditoria, estas tambien implican para el eliminado logico de los datos, por ejemplo: created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, created_by, deleted_by. Las que terminan en _at son de tipo TIMESTAMP y las que terminan en _by puede ser BIGINT que hace referencia para algún usuario del sistema.
12. Nombres en ingles, las tablas en plural, y los campos en singular.
13. El nombre para una tabla intermedia que relaciona dos tablas es separada con un subguion, por ejemplo: users y products se puede llamar users_products.

Es importante destacar que siempre hay exepciones dependiendo de las reglas de negocio, pero debe estar documentado para evitar malos entendidos.

Comment: **Gracias** por los consejos, los tomare muy en cuenta, no es para un trabajo ni algo por el estilo, soy estudiante de ingeniería en sistemas y la verdad quiero hacer bien las cosas, de antemano gracias Nicola.